# Using a lot of HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm making a login function for my website. I am using PHP to check if the user is logged in. If they are, I want to display the normal website, if not, I just want to display part of the website with a login button.

How can I do this without having to `echo` all of the html inside the PHP?

This is my code:

```
//conect to  database
//header & navigation

        <?php

        if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
            //user not logged in
            echo "</br>";
            steamlogin(); //login button    
        }  else {
            //user is logged in
            //all the code for normal website
            //(code includes HTML, JS, PHP)
        }
    ?>

//footer
```

Comment: my ideas: put the html that you want to show in an other file and include that if the user is loged in. Or more comonly: Check in the header if a user is logged in and if not redirect him to an information-page.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: If you're doing your own login script [don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
        //user not logged in
        echo "</br>";
        steamlogin(); //login button    
    }  else {
?>
        //user is logged in
        //all the code for normal website
        //(code includes HTML, JS, PHP)
<?php    
   }
?>
```

You can close the php tags after else and include normal html after that and then again start the php tag to render php code

Answer (score 1):

just close the php tag inside of the if statment like:   //conect to  database
//header & navigation

```
    <?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
        //user not logged in
        echo "</br>";
        steamlogin(); //login button    
    }  else {
        //user is logged in
        //all the code for normal website
        //(code includes HTML, JS, PHP)
?>
 <!-- html code -->

<?php
    }
?>
```

//footer

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is separation of concerns and templating.

So basically have all your logic (PHP) done first (before you output any HTML):

```
<?php

     // logic that works out if user is logged in, generating variables to use later
     // ...

     $logged_in = (isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) ? $_SESSION['steamid'] : null;
     $username = (isset($_SESSION['steamuser'])) ? $_SESSION['steamuser'] : null; // just for example

?>
```

... and then when you do your HTML templates (which will still need to be `.php` files so that the PHP tags get processed, i.e. `welcome.php`) you just wrap them in conditions like so:

```
<?php if ($logged_in): ?>
<h1>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?></h1>
<?php else: ?>
<h1>Welcome, please login.</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The tricky bit is organising the files as you'll no doubt want to re-use your authentication checks across the site. So you'll need an understanding of includes, and you could even look at how MVC (model-view-controller) frameworks work to improve your knowledge.